# Gatling vs httperf

Tags: gatling, httperf

I am trying to stress test one simple server with 10K connections per seconds; it's pretty dummy server so this should be possible.

When I run gatling, the best I can get is 7K, at 8K we start to receive connection errors. This is again a simple test, ramping to 8k and holding the traffic for 2 minutes.

```
Request 'Home' failed: java.net.ConnectException: Cannot assign requested address
```

I know this error is related to tuning our box (open files etc). I have tried some commands, but that didn't help much.

Anyway, when I run a simple burst test with httperf, I easily get 10K without any errors. Command line:

```
httperf --uri / --server cloud-10-0-20-35 --port 8080 --num-conns=500000 --rate 10000
```

Im on Centos 6.x VM box.

Why httperf is working different? I know its a native tool, but why such big difference? Any ideas? I am aware that this is more related of java infrastructure, then to Gatling itself - that is awesome tool.

Comment: What's your httperf command?

Comment: And what kind of errors do you get with Gatling?