# Specifying socket options in Gatling

Tags: sockets, tcp, gatling, time-wait

When perf-testing a dummy RESTful service I have ran into the `ConnectException: Cannot assign requested address` problem, described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gatling/rRpv8LPa51I) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28436560/gatling-vs-httperf), and applied the [tuning recommendations](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/general/operations.html) - increased the ephemeral port range to 10000-65000, my `ulimit -n` is 64000 and I have even enabled `net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse` and `net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle` - more info about these on this excellent blogpost [Coping with the TCP TIME-WAIT state on busy Linux servers](http://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2014-tcp-time-wait-state-linux.html) .

This still did not help, I still could simulate at most 10k requests per second (since in my test each user does only single request), so I've [scaled out](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/cookbook/scaling_out.html) to 4 and later 8 client machines. On 4 machines I could do 5k requests/s per machine (total of 20k) but on 8 I even can't run on those 5k, so maybe the problem is elsewhere.

Nevertheless, I'd like to ask if there are any options to set `SocketOptions` on the gatling connection, either through the Simulation or through gatling.conf - I'd like to use [SO_REUSEADDR](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/StandardSocketOptions.html#SO_REUSEADDR) there. Some options (connection timeouts) can be set in gatling.conf, but I haven't found this one.

Also, is there any document describing how does Gatling share connections? I would expect either a big connection pool where the 'users' grab their connection instances or dummy each-user-opens-his-connection, but somewhere I've read that there's a connection pool per user (who's he sharing the connections with, then? Or are these just cached connection used in his previous requests?).

**EDIT:** So the solution was simple in the end: use `.shareConnections` when setting `ScenarioBuilder.protocols(...)`. I have tried to use `-Dgatling.core.http.shareConnections` as command line arg (I am running the test from maven plugin) but it did not work; programmatic approach did.

Comment: One more note: even with `net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse` I still can see a lot of time_wait connections in `ss -iat`, and given those errors, I am not sure if it is applied correctly. Regrettably I cannot restart whole server without losing configuration - are there any particular services I should restart?

Comment: Oh thanks @Radim Vansa! Setting the `.shareConnections` fixed the issue for me. Without it I was unable to do over 500 requests per second. Using that with the `ulimit -n 64000` did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd like to use SO_REUSEADDR there.

Not possible atm. Will be in 2.2.

> is there any document describing how does Gatling share connections?

Yes, [here](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/http/http_protocol.html#connection-sharing). Default is one connection pool per virtual users, as a virtual users can use more than one concurrent connection when fetching resources, just like a browser. You can then switch to one shared global pool.